# SIGSEV in async tasks on Xamarin Android

Tags: android, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android, segmentation-fault

In our current Xamarin project for Android, we are seeing a whole lot of SIGSEGV in the mono-rt for our async tasks. Following is one such sample code that is generating about 20% of times SIGSEGV. Seems like I am doing something fundamentally wrong here or there is some serious issue with Xamarin for Android. Can someone help me point out what is wrong with this code that is generating this SIGSEGV?

Is this related to https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13707?

EDIT: I am seeing this kind of behavior all over the application now. Here is a [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6hF5zzklcnLZkE1R0ZRd2tjT1E/edit?usp=sharing) that has other errors. All the crashes are happening on async task code. Something really is wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

```
public async Task GetDataAsync(string downloadUri) {
    using (WebClient downloader = new WebClient ()) {
        downloader.Headers.Add ("x-bz-appId", "android");
        downloader.Headers.Add ("x-bz-authToken", Comman.AuthToken);
        downloader.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");

        var t = await downloader.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(downloadUri)).ContinueWith(downloadTask => {
            if (downloadTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) {
                JObject response = null;
                response = JObject.Parse(downloadTask.Result);
                return response;
            } else {
                if (downloadTask.Exception != null) {
                    throw downloadTask.Exception;
                } else {
                    throw new Exception(downloadTask.Status.ToString());
                }
            }
        });
        return t;
    }
}
```

```
[mono-rt] Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   at  <0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.__icall_wrapper_mono_array_new_specific (intptr,int) 
[mono-rt]   at System.Array.Resize (T[]&,int) 
[mono-rt]   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity (int) 
[mono-rt]   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.GrowIfNeeded (int) 
[mono-rt]   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Insert (int,T) 
[mono-rt]   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.InsertItem (int,Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken,bool) 
[mono-rt]   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.InsertItem (int,Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken,bool) 
[mono-rt]   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.AddInternal (int,object,bool) 
[mono-rt]   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.Add (object) 
[mono-rt]   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadContentFrom (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader) 
[mono-rt]   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadTokenFrom (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader) 
[mono-rt]   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader) 
[mono-rt]   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse (string) 
[mono-rt]   at Bloomz.Core.APIClient/c__async0/c__AnonStorey56.<>m__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1) [0x0004a] in /Users/hponnu/Projects/bloomz.native.android.2/Bloomz.Core/HelperClass/APIClient.cs:122
[mono-rt]   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskActionInvoker/FuncTaskInvoke`2.Invoke (System.Threading.Tasks.Task,object,System.Threading.Tasks.Task) 
[mono-rt]   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () 
[mono-rt]   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () 
[mono-rt]   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () 
[mono-rt]   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryExecuteTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task) 
[mono-rt]   at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextScheduler.TaskLaunchWrapper (object) 
[mono-rt]   at Android.App.SyncContext/c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/2a7b6821/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:18
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/2a7b6821/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1131/2a7b6821/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-12/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:71
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.18db936a-f8a6-4eb0-838d-1159fbb9846c (intptr,intptr) 
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.18db936a-f8a6-4eb0-838d-1159fbb9846c (intptr,intptr) 
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt]
```

Comment: Are you trying to run on the genymotion?

Comment: Yes, but I see the same issues on the phone too. On Genymotion this is happening at a higher frequency.

Comment: Do you get the result back from `downloadTask` (downloadTask.Result)? Does exception happen before that?

Comment: Hmm I used to have print statement printing the length of the string, and it was non-zero.

Comment: Is it possible to put together a self-contained test project that reproduces this issue so I can dig into it further?

Comment: Having only async/await actually reduced the frequency of errors but only after we moved to HTTPClient from WebClient the frequency went down much further. We are still seeing the failures but they are only happening on emulators and not the actual devices.

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters try to refactor your code so it uses the async syntax correctly, then you'll probably will see where your exception is originating from.
It seems that what you were trying to do was:

```
public async Task<JToken> GetDataAsync(string downloadUri) {
    using (WebClient downloader = new WebClient ()) {
        downloader.Headers.Add ("x-bz-appId", "android");
        downloader.Headers.Add ("x-bz-authToken", Comman.AuthToken);
        downloader.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");

        string unParsedResponse = null;
        try{
            unParsedResponse = await downloader.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(downloadUri));
        }
        cath(Exception ex){
            throw;
        }
        JObject response = null;
        response = JObject.Parse(unParsedResponse);
        return response;
    }
}
```

P.S. you really don't need the try-catch block there because awaiting a task will intercept any exception on it and as you don't really do anything except throwing it, the try catch is futile here.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I do "TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()" on the ContinueWith. I tried that, the frequency of the crashes has reduced but I still got them. BTW "downloadTask" is undefined in your code sample!

Comment: No, I'm suggesting you either use async syntax or manually handle Tasks with `ContinueWith()`, returning the Task, checking it's status, exceptions etc.  In your example you are doing both which is kinda wrong and could potentially be the cause for your exceptions.